# Converting date from the column to the unix_timestamp

Tags: mysql, date, unix-timestamp

I got date, stored in MySQL column like this: `09-11-2012` (format is `DD/MM/YYYY`), but when I do:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.date) FROM table t;
```

It does returns `0` for every single row.

How can I convert this format date to the unix timestamp? I would like to convert this date just like the PHP's `strtotime` is doing it.

Comment: You did not store the date in a VARCHAR column, did you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guest `t.date` is a string right? try converting it to `DATE` first using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(t.date, '%d-%m-%Y')) 
FROM table t;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5deeac/1)

Comment: That was it, I have converted date column type to the `date` instead of using the above function, but thank you for the tip!